# Jquery easyui datagrid restoring merged Cells

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I use mergeCells function in datagrid to merge some cells. But after deleting some of rows I need to restore grid without cell merge and apply merge again because some cells no longer has to be merged. How can I rebuild the grid without merged cells? 
`$('#dg').datagrid('reload');` does not help, it reloads but the merge remains.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Setting columns one more time on row delete function rebuilds the merge.

```
$('#dg').datagrid({
   columns : columns
});
```